# Set the a path containing [ ] on a URI

Tags: ruby, uri

I am trying to use URI to create an uri, but it seems that brackets ([]) are not accepted:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://example.com")
uri.path = URI.escape("/test[1].png")

URI::InvalidComponentError: bad component(expected absolute path component): /test[1].png
from /Users/something/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:823:in `check_path'
```

Any idea how to do? Should I just not use URI and just escape the uri at the end?

Comment: Yeah, just build your URI directly.

Comment: Turns out that [`URI.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html) is brain dead and doesn't agree with `URI` about what needs to be encoded. The source for it says `warn "#{caller(1)[0]}: warning: URI.escape is obsolete" if $VERBOSE` so it is apparently obsolete and shouldn't be used but there's no mention of what you should use instead. Wow. You can specify the characters to encode (`URI.escape("/test[1].png", '[]')`) but then you have specify **all of them**. There's `CGI.escape` but it does too much. There must be a sane way to do such a simple task.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend working with [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) for this.

While Ruby's built-in URI is convenient, it is showing some signs of age, and I suspect this is one. Addressable::URI has been proposed as a replacement for URI because it conforms with current RFCs and is more full-featured.

```
require 'addressable/uri'
Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/test[1].png")
=> #<Addressable::URI:0x81404710 URI:http://example.com/test[1].png>

Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/test[1].png").to_s
=> "http://example.com/test[1].png"
```

For simple, generic, uses I use URI, just because. For heavy-lifting I use Addressable::URI.

Comment: Broken link.  I believe this is the correct one now: https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable

Answer (score 1):

URI.escape takes additional parameter (string or regex, default is REGEXP::UNSAFE) to customize characters that you want to escape.

Try this:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://example.com")
uri.path = URI.escape("/test[1].png", "[]")
```

The URI::InvalidComponentError is because square brackets are not allowed in URIs, except for certain places. See [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986):

---

3.2.2.  Host

<...>

A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6 [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal within square brackets ("[" and "]"). **This is the only place where square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.**

---

Appendix D.  Changes from RFC 2396

D.1.  Additions

<...> **Square brackets are now specified as reserved within the authority component and are not allowed outside their use as delimiters for an IP literal within host.**

Comment: Not sufficient. The second parameter *replaces* the default replacement set so you'd need more than `'[]'` to cover all the cases.